How do we combine sensitivity in differential privacy with Lipschitz continuous?
The definition of sensitivity in differential privacy is: $s_{GS}(f) = max_{D1,D2}\|f(D_1)-f(D2)\|$ for two neighboring datasets $D_1, D_2$ (take global $l_1$ sensitivity as an example here), many literature would use Lipschitz continuous as a condition to conduct sensitivity of loss function, the definition of $l$ Lipschitz  continuous of a function $f:X \rightarrow R$ w.r.t. a norm $\|.\|$ is $|f(x)-f(x')| \leq l\|x-x'\|$, for some $l > 0$ and all $x, x' \in X$.
If we link the $l$-continuous with sensitivity, e.g., in DPSGD, consider $A\in R^{m*n}, x \in R^n, b \in R^m,$ find the sensitivity of $\nabla f,$ $f(x;A,b) = (Ax - b)^2$,
does this mean we view $f$ as the function of dataset $(A,b)$ instead of $x$ and put $l$-Lipschitz continuous on $f$, so we can reach: $\nabla f(x;A,b) \leq l$ and the sensitivity of $\nabla f$ is $2l$? And in DPSGD we assume this $l$-Lipschitz for all possible $x$?
(http://researchers.lille.inria.fr/abellet/teaching/private_machine_learning_course.html, lecture5, page 9)
